# How to save INT fields as null in laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm getting an error when saving some empty text, textarea fields. Laravel forms this sql query:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'inside_area' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `ads` (`street`, `quarter`, `building_number`, `inside_area`, `price`, `admin_comment`, `valid_to`, `price_heating`, `rooms`, `floor_number`, `floors_number`, `kitchen_area`, `years`, `public_comment`, `video_url`, `3d_url`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 1, 2017-03-13 14:33:50, 2017-03-13 14:33:50))
```

P.S. db table was created not in laravel way - I'm using existing tables, this may be important.

UPDATED: problem are only with INT fields, if they has empty form field on saving!

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `ads` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ad_type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `street` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quarter` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `building_number` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inside_area` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `show_price_per_meter` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price_heating` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `admin_comment` text,
  `valid_to` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `rooms` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `floor_number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `floors_number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `kitchen_area` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `balcony` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `balcony_glazed` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `years` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dyn_house_type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dyn_heating_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dyn_installation_ids` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `public_comment` text,
  `video_url` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `3d_url` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `available_for_trade` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

FORM:

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=>'ads']) !!}
    {!! Form::number('inside_area', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Route:

```
Route::resource('ads', 'AdsController');
```

Save action:

```
public function store() {
        $input = Request::all();
        \App\Ad::create($input);
        return redirect('/ads/my_index');
    }
```

P.S.2 If I provide any value to `inside_area` field, it goes ok and the next error is for `price` field.

Comment: Can you add your code that generates that Laravel query?

Comment: Maybe you need to insert the {inside_area} value as an integer? (e.g intval($inside_area)). There may be something about the data type of the value of the {inside_area} you've placed there.

Comment: I have added more code of this situation. If I provide numeric value for `inside_area` field, it goes ok, but the error goes for the second INT field with empty value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use attribute mutator for each integer attribute. In these mutators you can prepare data before inserting into DB.

In your case you should create mutators in your model Ads for every field with the type INT:

```
// define a mutator for the field "inside_area"
public function setInsideAreaAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['inside_area'] = (int) $value;
}
```

I understand that creating such a mutator for each INT field is boring, but it will also grant you ability to control user input before inserting into DB.

You can find more information about mutators here (for the latest version of Laravel at this moment):

- Laravel 5.4, Defining a Mutator:
  https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you are passing string data to 'inside_area' variable. Because there is more default null fields at your table, like 'city_id', 'ad_type_id'

Comment: I forgot to mention, that there is no form fields for some of table fields. So `inside_area` is the first INT field which has Form field, which is empty on saving. I have made field for `city_id` - so I got error also on it, if it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

another way is to use `Iatstuti` and provide in Ad.php model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Iatstuti\Database\Support\NullableFields;

class Ad extends Model {

    use NullableFields;

    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $nullable = [
        'inside_area'
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'ad_type_id',
        'inside_area'


    ];

}
```